# Trying to export to pdf using google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently trying to export a sheet as a pdf. This works fine using the getBlob() parameter, but I wish to export with a custom name of the file. When trying to use the following, the MimeType throws up an error message, and if removed the file is exported as plain text which I don't want. Any help would be great, either with exporting the file as a pdf or renaming it later

```
var sqc = ss.getSheetByName('SQC')
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID')
  //var pdf = folder.createFile(ss.getBlob());
var pdf = folder.createFile('New Text File', ss.getBlob, MimeType.exportPDF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding you are trying to export your Google Sheet to a PDF file.

**Here are some of my observations:**

- You are using an invalid [MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type), it should be `MimeType.PDF`
- When you use [createFile(name, content, mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename,-content,-mimetype), It expects a string input (Not a blob object). If you use a blob object as its content, the output pdf file will have the text `Blob` in it.

The most easiest way to export your sheet to pdf is to set your blob's name with file extension.

### Sample Replication:

```
  var blob = ss.getBlob();

  // Test 1, set the file name and mimetype using createFile()
  folder.createFile("Test1",blob,MimeType.PDF);

  // Test 2, set the file name with extension in the blob object
  blob.setName("Test2.pdf");
  folder.createFile(blob);
```

### Output:

[image]

**Test1**

[image]

**Test2**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I was able to sort it out. Just chuck in

```
pdf.setName = "Name"
```